# WPF: Open source of xaml control examples

Tags: wpf, xaml, open-source, controls

I'm teaching myself WPF and xaml by replicating existing controls and UI from AutoCAD 2010 and Excel 2010.  Once the various controls are polished, I would be happy to share any code.  Is there sites or communities that are open source and WPF or xaml based?

[WPF Control Example http://cartesia.pbworks.com/f/1260580772/ControlSample.png](http://cartesia.pbworks.com/f/1260580772/ControlSample.png)

Comment: Are you after examples (of which there are quite a few on CodePlex for example) or a community site for control writers / XAML developers?  Your question and title seem slightly different...

Comment: A community site for control writers / XAML developers.  Something more than snippets.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  This is the rationale behind Microsoft's own [Microsoft Expression Gallery](http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/en-us/) site.

It is a community site for snippets, controls, behaviors, samples, and other XAML/WPF/Silverlight related assets.

Comment: Thanks Reed, exactly what I was after!